# Problems when saving keyboard input to CArray and outputting to static text

Tags: mfc

I used `CArray` to do Static Text with `SetWindowText(arr.GetDate())` and the result is something like this

[image]

The result when inputting 1 is the above image. The upper part uses `CString` and the lower part uses `CArray`. You can use `CString`, but I want to know why.

Thanks for answers 
In the subclass.h file of CFormView, define the CArray  m_arr variable and add wm_char as the keystroke event in the .cpp file

```
Void CMyCalcView :: OnChar (UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags) 
{ 
M_arr.Add (nChar); 
CFormView :: OnChar (nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags); 
}
```

Using wm_paint as a drawing event

```
Void CMyCalcView :: OnPaint () 
{ 
CPaintDC dc (this); 
M_staticText.SetWindowText (m_arr.GetData ()); // m_staticText is a resource 
}
```

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: CArray<> of what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CArray must be of type TCHAR, and be aware that SetWindowText will not work without a terminating 0 character.

And you have to delimiter so SetWindowText takes all data behind your char.

Using CString would be the better solution.